# Can't run jar file in a Debian Server

Tags: java, jar, debian, executable-jar

I have a java application that I can't run on a Debian Server (it runs locally). This is the reason:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TimeSeriesEntry : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

Then I checked the version and I got this:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

If it is a version problem, how can I update to the newest version?

This is the server I am running it:

```
# uname -a
Linux iWidgetServer1 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PS: Jar was created with Eclipse (Export -> Runnable Jar) in a Linux Mint 14 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of JDK did you build the jar with and what version are you trying to run it on.

I believe you compiled and built with JDK 7 and then are trying to run on JDK 6

Comment: This is what I also believe. This is the Java I run on my PC: `chris@mint-desktop ~ $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.10.1)`

Comment: Yep that is the problem. You built it with JDK 7 and are deploying on JDK 6. Just update java on the debian server. Something along the lines of `su apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just needed to run `update-alternatives --config java` in order to select the new Java environment.